# Can Qt Creator be used to debug QNX Neutrino builds?

Tags: qt, gdb, qt-creator, qnx, qnx-neutrino

I've gotten so used to using Qt Creator that I'd like to use it as an IDE for a QNX project I'm doing (QNX 6.3.0). Code editing--check. Compiling--I'm pretty sure I can get that to work. Debugging--well I'm stuck. QNX Momentics distributes a cross debugger, 'ntox86-gdb.exe'. I can use this debugger from the command line with no problem. I cannot figure out how to get Creator to use it as a debugger. Has anybody tried something like this?

New info: I've gotten as far as this: I can go to the Debug menu, select Start Debugging->Start and Attach to Remote Application, type in my debugger (ntox86-gdb.exe), executable, and the IP/port of my target. When I click OK, there's a long pause, and finally a dialog: "The gdb process exited unexpectedly (code 101120)"

Answer (score 1):

Looks like something to that effect just happened:

```
commit 17c18623ef419ee46bb52553324974530e03b1df
Date:   Fri Feb 10 07:42:44 2012 +0100

Add support for the remote QNX debugging protocol
```